# Error in Estimote Sample Code?

Tags: c#, estimote

First off, I'm a C++ programmer now learning how to use Visual Studio and C# both at the same time.

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/estimotesdkandroid

This is my upcoming project for android, I'm using C# to implement this but the sample code is giving me some problems.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.notify_demo);

        _region = this.GetBeaconAndRegion().Item2;
        _beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
    }
```

My Item2 is red underlined in VS, the error is

```
"object does not contain a definition for 'Item2' and no extension method 'Item2' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

Tried to google the error but can't understand the answer provided by the community.

As far as I understand, this is not a careless mistake of me forgetting to add something in the assembly reference and using directive. Probably...

Comment: The error means that the type that the GetBeaconAndRegion method returns (a generic object, it sounds like) does not contain a property called 'Item2'. If you know the type, then you can cast the return value first, or modify the method to return a strongly typed object (one with an 'Item2' property).

Comment: @RufusL But the problem is the function definition is not even in the documentation page itself.

Comment: What type does `this.GetBeaconAndRegion()` return? You should include that in your question. You can put your cursor over the method call and Press F12 in Visual Studio to jump to the method definition.

Comment: @mason I have no idea what it is supposed to return. I'm trying to figure how app works for beacons but the sample code isn't working for me and is lack of documentation. Made a ticket in Estimote forum and the developer says that I should move to Android Studio instead. Which the documentation is provided by themselves and is more understandable. Thanks for offering your help anyway!